# Snowflake SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: ssl, ssh, certificate, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing data load via ODBC, by extracting data from on prem database into files and then importing those into Snowflake target table.

During that process, I am getting the error mentioned below. What could be the possibility of getting this error?

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL <hiding Snowflake URL> failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=2 osMsg='No such file or directory'.
 
ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL <hiding Snowflake URL> failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=2 osMsg='No such file or directory'.
"

At C:\temp\wsla3205x.ps1:254 char:5
+ $sfOdbc.Open()
```

Is there any more information required on this from my side?

Comment: That usually means you have a proxy/firewall in between that breaks the flow. Have also a look [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/CURLerror-SSL-peer-certificate-or-SSH-remote-key-was-not-OK-during)

Comment: Thanks for replying @Sergiu. I have checked that link already. It is for "osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'". Mine is osCode=2. Although I still tried to implement the solution mentioned in that link, still no luck. Btw I have no firewalls/proxy in place. Or do you mean I need to check that on Snowflake web client, if it has one?

Comment: Even if the message looks a bit different than in that post, I still think you may have a device in your network that inspects the SSL on the Snowflake account URL. I would run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) and see if it is successful.